Firebase Auth Gate not working in Flutter web
I have developed this application  in flutter web and I am using firebase for Auth and I have this Auth gate that will check if the user have a session and if yes then redirect to the Dashboard but if not then move to the Login Page.
But the issue is that this Auth Gate is not working here is the code of Auth Gate:
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rafay_portfolio/frontend/admin/pages/dashboardPage.dart';
import 'package:rafay_portfolio/frontend/admin/pages/auth/loginPage.dart';

class AuthGate extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthGate({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const DashboardPage();
          } else {
            return const LoginAdmin();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


I am using Login email with opt as well, everytime I refresh this page the auth gate does not check for session and alway redirect to the login page.
This is code for Login using Firebase:
// ignore_for_file: use_build_context_synchronously

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rafay_portfolio/frontend/admin/pages/auth/opt.dart';
import 'package:rafay_portfolio/frontend/admin/pages/dashboardPage.dart';
import 'package:rafay_portfolio/constants/widgets/dialogBox/dialogbox.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<UserCredential?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      BuildContext context, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      return userCredential;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showDialogBox(
        context,
        Icons.error,
        Colors.red,
        Colors.red,
        'Error',
        e.message ?? 'An error occurred.',
        () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      );
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> handleLogin(BuildContext context, String email, String password,
      String phoneNumber) async {
    UserCredential? userCredential =
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(context, email, password);

    // If the user is authenticated, start the phone number verification process
    if (userCredential != null && userCredential.user != null) {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const DashboardPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          showDialogBox(
            context,
            Icons.error,
            Colors.red,
            Colors.red,
            'Error',
            e.message ?? 'An error occurred.',
            () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          );
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => OtpPage(
                verificationId: verificationId,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          showDialogBox(
            context,
            Icons.error,
            Colors.red,
            Colors.red,
            'Error',
            'Sorry OTP Expired',
            () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
}



The Project is hosted on github and the link is: https://github.com/rafay99-epic/Portfolio
All the changes are in V1 and I do have a pull request as well.
Have a look at the code base or help me to identify the Problem.
